# Templating git merge default message

Tags: git, merge, message, commit

Is it possible to change the default message `"Merge branch foo into bar"` into something else, so `merge --no-ff` will always show a template like `"Adding features xyz"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git merge <branch> --no-ff -m "Adding features xyz"
```

An alias could make it shorter, `git config --global -e` and paste the following alias.

```
[alias]
        mg = !git merge $1 --no-ff -m \"Adding feature xyz\"
```

So `git mg <branch>` will work.

The commit message template can be written in a file.

```
git merge <branch> --no-ff -m "$(cat <msg_template_path>)"
```

or

```
[alias]
        mg = !git merge $1 --no-ff -m \"$(cat <msg_template_path>)\"
```

Comment: I hoped there would be a more "standard" way of doing this. I want the template to be dynamic, so xyz could be foo/bar/whatever feature I implemented in this merge.